# How to force Xcode to relink

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I update a source file (not a header) in Xcode in one library, Xcode doesn't seem to know when to relink with that library.

Is there a way to force xcode to relink without having to clean or modify a header file?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but i believe that if you drop the latest source file in the same location and overright the previous version of the file. Xcode will pick the latest source file

Comment: There seem to be issues with the timestamp of the file: If you drop a file in the same position that has an older modification time than the original file the dependency tracking does not seem to count this as a change.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai for pointing that out, i have got no idea that timestamp will affect how the dependancy works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the library as a subproject, remember to add it as a 'Target Dependency' in Build Phases.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply go to **Product -> Clean** and the when you **Rebuild** it **must** *compile* and *relink* everything

Comment: syvex was explicitly asking for a solution "without having to clean".

Comment: Read better, he ask "without having to _clean or modify_ a **header file**", not project. If under header file he mean project then it's wrong question, not my answer...